# Why can't I find anything in BeautifulSoup documentation about .text or content method?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, documentation

At the moment I am following a Python course on Udemy and I am learning the concept of web scraping. The way this is done is as follows:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = requests.get("http://example.com/")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, "lxml")
```

Now, I cannot find anything about the text method of Beautifulsoup in the documentation. I know this because it is clearly explained in the course I am following.

Is this usual? I am asking this more from a general point of view when searching for relevant information in future documentation.

Comment: Because that's an attribute coming from an object in the requests library, that's only the *input* to BeautifulSoup. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content.

Comment: Thank you! That was not entirely clear to me, until now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the .text attribut, because if you use just url in your case, you only get the statuscode of your request, which can not be a parameter in your soup object.

Comment: Thank you! I got the error TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len(), but that explains why I got that.